In localhost netwrok, spl-token create-token is error
In localhost network TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA token program is not exit. How deploy this.

I'm not sure how you started your validator, but if you setup any new test validator, the token program is present:
solana-test-validator -r

And in another window:
$ solana -ul account TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA

Public Key: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
Balance: 0.9290208 SOL
Owner: BPFLoader2111111111111111111111111111111111
Executable: true
Rent Epoch: 0
Length: 133352 (0x208e8) bytes
0000:   7f 45 4c 46  02 01 01 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00   .ELF............
... trimmed for length ...

